# How do I make the "dates" appear in sequential order on a Query that searches more than one table?

Tags: mysql

I have tried to make this question as generic as possible... I have 3 tables in a single database called "Widget Sales". They are as follows:

```
Table_1 = Purchase dates of "Small Widgets" by a Dealer. 
Table_2 = Purchase dates of "Medium Widgets" by a Dealer. 
Table_3 = Purchase dates of "Large Widgets" by a Dealer.
```

I use a simple query to search all 3 tables for purchases made by a specific Dealer, in this case the ACME Widget Company of Walla Walla, Washington. (*beep, beep*)

```
SELECT "Dealer", "Item", "Purchase Date"
FROM "Table_1"
WHERE "Dealer" = 'ACME'
UNION
SELECT "Dealer", "Item", "Purchase Date"
FROM "Table_2"
WHERE "Dealer" = 'ACME'
UNION
SELECT "Dealer", "Item", "Purchase Date"
FROM "Table_3"
WHERE "Dealer" = 'ACME'
```

This query places the search results in the following sequence as shown in EXAMPLE A:

**First**: The search results from "Table_1" returned 2 "Small" Widgets

**Second**: The search results from "Table_2" returned 1 "Medium" Widget.

**Third**: The search results from "Table_3" returned 1 "Large" Widget.

```
EXAMPLE A | Current Query Results

Dealer                  Item                          Purchase Date
===================================================================
ACME                    Small Widget                  06/28/2011
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ACME                    Small Widget                  09/03/2011
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
ACME                    Medium Widget                 07/21/2011
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ACME                    Large Widget                  08/05/2011
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**My Question is:** What do I need to do to my existing query to have the purchase dates appear in sequencial order as shown in Example B?

I am sure this is " SQL 101" but I'm new at this so I really appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

```
EXAMPLE B | Proposed Query Results

Dealer                  Item                          Purchase Date
===================================================================
ACME                    Small Widget                  06/28/2011
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ACME                    Medium Widget                 07/21/2011
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ACME                    Large Widget                  08/05/2011
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ACME                    Small Widget                  09/03/2011
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Add `ORDER BY "Purchase Date"` at the bottom of the query

Comment: @SQLMenace, why didn't you post this as an answer, instead of a comment?  Then the OP could have marked it as correct if suitable.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
SELECT "Dealer", "Item", "Purchase Date"
FROM "Table_1"
WHERE "Dealer" = 'ACME'
UNION
SELECT "Dealer", "Item", "Purchase Date"
FROM "Table_2"
WHERE "Dealer" = 'ACME'
UNION
SELECT "Dealer", "Item", "Purchase Date"
FROM "Table_3"
WHERE "Dealer" = 'ACME'
)
ORDER BY "Purchase Date";
```

This is a bit dodgy but should work. If you use union query often, you might consider restructuring your database, by adding another field which would decide which table it is going in now...

Comment: Unfortunately the system I am using (ZOHO Reports) does not support "FROM" in their query??? Looks like an interesting way to approach my question thou. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an Order By clause:

```
 SELECT "Dealer", "Item", "Purchase Date" 
  FROM "Table_1" 
 WHERE "Dealer" = 'ACME' 
  UNION
 SELECT "Dealer", "Item", "Purchase Date" 
 FROM "Table_2" 
 WHERE "Dealer" = 'ACME' 
  UNION 
 SELECT "Dealer", "Item", "Purchase Date" 
 FROM "Table_3" 
 WHERE "Dealer" = 'ACME' 
 Order By "Purchase Date"
```

Comment: Thank you Charles that did it. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.